# Coldfusion web service returning null instead of JSON Struct

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I'm working on a chat app that uses an ajax call to a Coldfusion web service that will return the values in a struct. Here is the js

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $bPath,
    contentType: "application/JSON; charset=utf-8",
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        //alert(data);
    },
    error: function(data,status,error){
        alert('Something went wrong: '+data+', '+status+', '+error);
    },
    dataType: 'JSON'
}).done(function(api) {
        console.log( api );
        $('#chatBox').append('<div class="messageEntry"><span>'+api.TIMESTAMP+': </span><span><strong>'+api.NAME+'</strong></span>: <span>'+api.MESSAGE+'</span></div>');
        $('#chatBox').scrollTop($('#chatBox')[0].scrollHeight);
        $("#messageInput").val('');


});
```

and here is the CFC

CFC:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="newMessage" access="remote" returntype="Struct" returnformat="JSON"> 

        <cfset params = toString( getHttpRequestData().content ) />
        <cfset args = #deserializeJSON(params)# />

        <cfset timeStamp = #args.time# />
        <cfset newMessage = #args.message# />
        <cfset userID = #args.userID# />

        <cfquery name="qryemp" datasource="HR">
            select EmployeeID, name_last, name_first, Email
            from tblRegionIIEmployee
            where Username = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#userID#">
        </cfquery>    

        <cfset myResult={timeStamp="#args.time#", name="#qryemp.name_first# #qryemp.name_last#", message="#args.message#"} />
        <cfreturn myResult>

    </cffunction> 
</cfcomponent>
```

I am not showing any errors anywhere, In firebug it just shows the response as null. Why doesn't the web service return my data?

Comment: it looks like you are just returning the result of the query, I'm not familiar enough with cold fusion, does returning it actually print out the value? And also, it likes you are returning the direct result, not a json encoding of the result, again not familiar enough with CF to say for sure

Comment: All it returns is "Null." No data at all. No errors either. responseHeaders show no problems. CF when you specify returnformat json it will send the data back as json. the data query isn't whats being returned by itself. it is put into the object that is returning data

Comment: First, did you [test the function in your browser](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0ac4a-7fd9.html) to verify it works before plugging it into jquery? Second, why use `getHttpRequestData().content` instead of `cfargument`? (As an aside, always `var/local` scope all function local variables).

Comment: Thanks Leigh in answer to your question. the beforeSend: function() {
        //alert(data);
    } handles the test to see the data when Im sending. It turns out this works fine with no problem. Apparently another developer I was working with tried to work on it while I was gone and messed it up then created a ghost file in the directory which threw the whole thing off. I had to rebuild the directory. I highly doubt anyone else will have this problem.

Comment: Glad you figured things out. *RE: I highly doubt anyone else will have this problem* Since it turned out to be a localized problem, you may just want to delete the question.